# Strange Behavior in Scrolling UIScrollView to UITextView hidden by keyboard

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have looked at a number of posts here on scrolling and unhiding a UITextField and believed that the same code should work for a UITextView, but that seems not to be the case. The first issue I encountered was that the sample app I have is an iPad app supporting landscape orientation only. The keyboard size returned from the notification had the height and width of the keyboard reversed.

Next, while I can get the scrollview to scroll the textview, it does not reveal all of it and in fact the amount of the textview that is shown is dependent on where I tap in the textview. It is more like it is scrolling to where the cursor will be which is not what I want.

Here is the code I am using. It was taken from an example, the only real change is that a UITextView is used instead of a UITextField. If the only thing I do is to replace the textview with a textfield it works fine.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.width, 0.0);
    _myscrollview.contentInset = contentInsets;
    _myscrollview.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.width;
    DebugLog(@"textview = %@", _textview);

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _textview.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, _textview.frame.origin.y-kbSize.width);
        [_myscrollview setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to scroll to the top of your UITextView you can do that by

```
[textview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:YES];
```

Try messing with the below method. Perhaps set it to the height of the textView. Can you post a screenshot of the issue?

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
}
```

Comment: No, what I want to to is to make the UITextView fully visible. The code I submitted works fine with a UITextField when the keyboard hides it, but it does not work for a UITextView. The UITextView is only partially revealed and how much of it that is revealed is dependent on where I tapped in the UITextView. If I tap in the top of the view, only a small portion of UITextView is uncovered. If I tap at the bottom of the UITextView most of it is uncovered.  It is as if the origin for the UITextView's frame is changed based upon where I tapped.

Comment: textView.selectedRange. Try messing with that.

Comment: MarkM's suggestion of playing with the textView.selectedRange provided the answer that I was looking for. It was pretty clear that the textView was returning the insertion point as the origin and the view then was scrolled to make visible the insertion point, not the entire view as I desired. So I set the range to textView.text.length for location and 0 for for its length which is defined as an insertion point and the entire textView was scrolled to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided the correct method [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW2) (check the Listing 4-1). It works for both UITextField and UITextView. We do not need to edit the range or anything else. It should be the scrollview that needs handling. The one marked as 'Answered' may work, but we better follow the creator's method!